# Difference between 2 SQL tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables: tableA and tableB. How can I get all the records that are in tableA but not in tableB? I am interested in the proper way to do this, not workarounds. I've tried using a left join and then adding `where ID is not null`. It works, but I am not sure whether that is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from tableA
where id not in (select id from tableB)
```

or

```
select * from tableA a
left join tableB b on a.id = b.id
where b.id is null
```

Both are totally acceptable ways to retrieve what you asked.

Comment: Is the one without join supposed to be faster? Or they're totally the same? I've always been told that joins should almost only be used when displaying data from 2 tables, otherwise, use select.. from.. where in select...

Comment: I think it depends. I did an `explain select ...` of both queries on tables of my DB and the 1st statement did a full table scan on `null` keys. The 2nd did not. But if performance is an issue i would recommend to run both queries with an `explain` and see the differences.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use join for this if you need to show the data on the page (programming), in case you need to move your data from one table to another table for backup or other similar purpose, you need a sql compare tool.
For first on you need sql left join. Make your table A as left one and put and join with B

```
select * from A
left join B  on A.id = B.id
where b.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`. I prefer to use `NOT EXISTS`  because when the columns allow nulls but has none, the `NOT IN` performs significantly worse than `NOT EXISTS`.

```
Select * from table1 a
    Where not exists (Select ID from table2 b where a.ID = b.ID)
```

On `non-nullable` columns, you can use either of them which fits to your situation as the behaviour and performance of `NOT IN` and NOT EXISTS are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Sql fiddle [][1]

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10300/2) http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10300/2

`select * from table1 where id not in(select id from table2)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given the table schema lets assume that there are primary key in each table.id1,id2

YOU Can do with the help of left join.

Select * from table1 left join table2 where id2 is null

NOte this is not an actual query just a hint for you to go ahead.